# Error at init.el and orgmode export

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-export, org-babel

I reinstalled my whole system and after trying to load my previous Emacs config that works in the past, I always obtain an error: 
`org-define-error` and I follow de conflict line what is `(require 'ox-beamer)` but I can't find this package but in my last installation of Emacs it works. Anybody knows what's happening here?

Comment: Did you install any package from ELPA? Perhaps you should try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24735377)?

Comment: I tryed what comments in the link but doesn't work for me  @przemq

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the version of org, new is the 8 version but emacs on fedora should come with 7 version, this problem is fixed in sacha sua blogs:

http://sachachua.com/blog/2014/05/update-org-7-comes-emacs-org-8-configuration-better-exports/